# Can't reshape color palette tuples using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following code which gets the color palette from series of images and try to reshape the output using numpy reshape. but when I try reshaping the output I get the error can't reshape array of size 27 into shape (3,3).

The output of Colours array print out is like this

```
[(256,256,265),(256,256,265),(256,256,265),(256,256,265),(256,256,265),(256,256,265),(256,256,265),(256,256,265),(256,256,265)]
```

Which are 9 tuples containing the colour palette which supposedly can be reshaped into 3 * 3
But numpy.reshape keeps saying it is 27 items and can't be reshaped into 3*3 array,
My question is how can I reshape this output into 3 * 3 array

So The colour array I need  after reshaping should look something like this:

```
colours=[
[(256,256,265),(256,256,265),(256,256,265)],
[(256,256,265),(256,256,265),(256,256,265)],
[(256,256,265),(256,256,265),(256,256,265)]
        ]
```

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

array=[]
for row in range(1,4):
    for column in range(1,4):
        filename = '/storage/emulated/0/python/banana/banana_0'+str(row)+'_0'+str(column)+'.png'
        img = Image.open(filename)
        img.show()

        colors = img.getpixel((10,10))
        array.append(colors)

array=np.array(array)
box_array=array.reshape(3,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape using the full destination shape. Your array contains 27 elements in total
When you do:

```py
array = np.array(array)
```

you obtain a (9, 3) shaped array, so you can't reshape it in (3, 3), but in (3, 3, 3).

you can proceed like:

```py
box_array = array.reshape(3, 3, 3)
```

Depending on what dimension is subject to change in your array later, you can let numpy figure it out.
If for instance your 2nd and 3rd dimensions will always be (3, 3), then you can reshape your array as follows and numpy will detect automatically the 1st dimension:

```py
box_array = array.reshape(-1, 3, 3)
```

And inversely if your 1st and 2nd dimensions will always be (3, 3), then you can reshape your array as follows and numpy will detect automatically the 3rd dimension:

```py
box_array = array.reshape(3, 3, -1)
```